# Doesn't work setting default value of property in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have a boolean property in my entity. Here's my annotations for it:

```
@Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE", nullable = false, columnDefinition="BIT DEFAULT 1", length = 1)
public Boolean getActive() {
    return isActive;
}
```

But `columnDefinition="BIT DEFAULT 1"` doen't work perfectly. Here's SQL code I get as result for generated table:

```
IS_ACTIVE BIT(1) NOT NULL,
```

What am I doing wrong?

And so when I try to save an instance of this class to the database  I get the exception:

```
`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'IS_ACTIVE' cannot be null`
```

If I remove `nullable = false` property:

```
@Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE", columnDefinition="BIT DEFAULT 1", length = 1)
public Boolean getActive() {
    return isActive;
}
```

so I can save a created object in this case. But it's still the **default value is not set** and I get NULL in the value of this field in database.

Any ideas please? I use MySQL Server 5.1 if it's important. I would be very grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try using `BOOLEAN` data type, define your `@Column` annotation like that:

```
@Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE", columnDefinition = "boolean default true", nullable = false)
private Boolean active = true;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. Only BIT type has changed to TINYINT in database. But all the same it's not received the default value. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Yes, of course. I still use **create-drop** of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in test mode. And now I have `IS_ACTIVE TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',` in database. It's very well! But why is default value NULL? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: And I again get the exception `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'IS_ACTIVE' cannot be null` when I am trying to save an instance of this class...

Comment: Try to initialize boolean value in class as well. Updated my asnwer.

Comment: Or change Boolean to primitive boolean.

Comment: It's work properly. Thank you! Is this approach  good practice? (initialize a variable in the Java code and not in the database) Or is this issue cannot be solved by different way?

Comment: If you want to set default to some entity variable you need to do it in Java code and in database. Then you need not worry about how do you put your object to database by executing SQL `insert` or persisting entity with ORM.

Comment: @AleksandrM but wouldn't that create a maintenance overhead, it will be maintained in both db and java code ?

Answer (score 2):

reference to the correct answer in this link [How to set default value in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110266/how-to-set-default-value-in-hibernate)

If you want a real database default value, use columnDefinition - @Column(name = “myColumn”, nullable = false, columnDefinition = “int default 100"). Notice that the string in columnDefinition is database dependent. Also if you choose this option, **you have to use dynamic-insert, so Hibernate doesn't include columns with null values on insert. Otherwise talking about default is irrelevant.**

The key of the solution is dynamic-insert annotation. You can add it to your entity class as this example: `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicInsert = true)`