# Is there any Spring Annotation to Set Default value for a Field (Mongo)?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

Is there any Spring Annotation to Set Default value for a Field (Mongo) ?

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? I believe you've got the wrong answer from the ***answer*** below, it is better for you to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28134682/1867076

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No need for spring annotations, this should do the trick:

```
     import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
     import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;


    @Document
    public class Doc {

    @Field
    private String field = "CustomDefaultValue"; 

    }
```

Comment: Is there any spring annotation ?

Comment: @GauravAgrawal No, there's nothing like this. Available annotations are available here : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-annotations

Comment: not really a good idea because if the same model used for data coming from the front-end it's hard to tell whether it's a default value or it's provided from the front-end.

Comment: this would probably work `public String getImageType() { return imageType == null ? 'PNG' : imageType; }` and I'm don't think `@Field` annotation is needed

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell your Builder to use default value for some field using @Builder.Default(annotation).

Like this,

```
    @Builder
    @Document
    public class Document {

    @Builder.Default
    private String field = "any_value"; 

    }
```