# Correct way to add default value at database level with Hibernate 6 and Spring boot 3

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have columns on which I require default value at DB level. Before hibernate 6, hibernate never fired alter query to change DB or alter length. The problem is we used to write default keyword with value in column definition which is not a valid syntax in alter query.

So is there any way I can add default value in hibernate 6.

I am using SQL Server. PFA code snippet

```
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8559071964734620120L;

@CreatedBy
@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "CREATED_BY", updatable = false)
private Integer createdBy;

@CreatedDate
@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE", columnDefinition="datetime default GETDATE()", updatable = false)
private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

@LastModifiedBy
@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED_BY")
private Integer lastModifiedBy;

@LastModifiedDate
@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();
```

}

query generated by hibernate looks like this

```
alter table TABLE_NAME alter column CREATED_DATE datetime default GETDATE()
```

exception is

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table TABLE_NAME alter column CREATED_DATE datetime default GETDATE()" via JDBC [Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'.]
```

I know default value is a constraint and to add it we have to write different syntax(add constraint) but is there any hibernate way (correct way of doing that).

Note: All these alter query is getting fired because how instant is now being stored and because it has default value, i get these exceptions.

Thanks @siggemannen for answer's link[default value with annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107554/define-default-column-value-with-annotations-in-hibernate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a default entity property value with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110266/how-to-set-a-default-entity-property-value-with-hibernate)

Comment: @siggemannen no it will raise the exception, in my code snippet i am using the same way.

Comment: Huh, i don't see your code mention `@ColumnDefault` annotation at all, don't look at accepted answer but at all answers

Comment: @siggemannen sorry i missed that completely, will try that and let you know.

Comment: @siggemannen thanks it worked, link for direct answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107554/define-default-column-value-with-annotations-in-hibernate